# Selecting specific rows and following ones which meet certain criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset [df] such as this:

```
id   device   date                pressure    warning
1    B3       2020-04-15 08:00    112         0
2    B3       2020-04-15 09:00    67          1
3    B3       2020-04-15 10:00    13          0
4    B3       2020-04-15 11:00    0           0
5    B3       2020-04-15 12:00    12          0
6    B3       2020-04-15 13:00    28          0
7    B3       2020-04-16 09:00    120         0
8    B3       2020-04-16 10:00    80          1
9    B3       2020-04-16 11:00    0           0
10   B3       2020-04-16 12:00    19          0
11   B3       2020-04-16 13:00    30          0
```

I need to select the ones which have a warning [1] and I also need to select the first row after a warning whith the pressure value higher than 20 [pressure >= 20].

The expected result would look like this:

```
id   device   date                pressure    warning
2    B3       2020-04-15 09:00    67          1
6    B3       2020-04-15 13:00    28          0
8    B3       2020-04-16 10:00    80          1
11   B3       2020-04-16 13:00    30          0
```

Is there any way of doing this in R or SQL?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Why does your expected result show 2 where pressure >= 20 and the question asks 'select the first row whith the pressure value higher than 20'?

Comment: Sorry about that. I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Basic idea is to first group the df by "warnings groups". Inside the groups we can then pick the first obs which triggered the warnng as well as the first following obs where pressure is above 20. Thanks to @Ben for simplifying my original code considerably:

### Edit:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(warning)) %>% 
  filter(any(warning == 1), warning == 1 | pressure >= 20) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  # Drop helpers
  select(-grp)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   warning1 [2]
#>   warning1 id    device     date  pressure warning
#>      <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <int>   <int>
#> 1        1 B3    2020-04-15 09:00       67       1
#> 2        1 B3    2020-04-15 13:00       28       0
#> 3        2 B3    2020-04-16 10:00       80       1
#> 4        2 B3    2020-04-16 13:00       30       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Original Code:

```r
df %>% 
  # Warnings group
  mutate(warning1 = cumsum(warning)) %>%
  # Group by warnings group
  group_by(warning1) %>%
  # Pressure counter by warnings group
  mutate(pressure1 = cumsum(pressure >= 20 & warning == 0)) %>% 
  # Filter: 
  # 1. Keep obs where warning is initiated (warning == 1)
  # 2. Keep first following obs with pressure >= 20 
  filter(warning == 1 | (warning1 > 0 & pressure >= 20 & warning == 0 & pressure1 == 1)) %>% 
  # Drop helpers
  select(-warning1, -pressure1)
```

Comment: stefan, how about simplifying to this: `df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(warning)) %>%
  filter(any(warning == 1), warning == 1 | pressure >= 20) %>% slice(1:2)`? seems to give similar answer

Comment: Hi @Ben. Absolutely. This is a considerable simplification of the code. Thx. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: No problem - if you'd like, you can edit your answer and include as alternative. All good.

Comment: Hi, this works fine, I get a result with the expected number of rows, however, all my rows and columns contain only NAs and the row index, contains values such as (NA, NA.1, NA.2...). Do you know what this could mean? Thank you very much.

Comment: Most probably there are missings in your real dataset, e.g. if the are `NA` in `warning` then the grouping via `cumsum()`. I would recommend you check for missings in your dataset. Next the question is how to deal with them, e.g. drop such obs?, replace missings, ...

Comment: You are right, that was the was. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution

Logic is as same as @stefan's answer.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('id device  date                pressure    warning
1   B3      2020/4/15 8:00  112 0
2   B3      2020/4/15 9:00  67  1
3   B3      2020/4/15 10:00 13  0
4   B3      2020/4/15 11:00 0   0
5   B3      2020/4/15 12:00 12  0
6   B3      2020/4/15 13:00 28  0
7   B3      2020/4/16 9:00  120 0
8   B3      2020/4/16 10:00 80  1
9   B3      2020/4/16 11:00 0   0
10  B3      2020/4/16 12:00 19  0
11  B3      2020/4/16 13:00 30  0
')


dt[,grp:=cumsum(warning)]

dt[warning==1|pressure>20&grp>0,head(.SD,2),by=.(grp)]
#>    grp id device            date pressure warning
#> 1:   1  2     B3  2020/4/15 9:00       67       1
#> 2:   1  6     B3 2020/4/15 13:00       28       0
#> 3:   2  8     B3 2020/4/16 10:00       80       1
#> 4:   2 11     B3 2020/4/16 13:00       30       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
ind1 <- which(df$warning==1)
ind2 <- which(df$pressure >= 20)
dfout <- df[sort(c(ind1,sapply(ind1, function(x) min(ind2[ind2 > x])))),]
```

such that

```
> dfout
   id     device  date pressure warning
2  B3 2020-04-15 09:00       67       1
6  B3 2020-04-15 13:00       28       0
8  B3 2020-04-16 10:00       80       1
11 B3 2020-04-16 13:00       30       0
```